# ruby each_<size_of_block> equivalent to each_byte

Tags: ruby, stream, block

How to read a whole file blockwise in ruby? 
e.g. megabyte:

```
files.each do |filename|
    f=File.new(filename)
    f.each_block(1024) {|megabyte|
        print megabyte      
    }
end
```

I want to use this code in a CGI to merge TS files on the fly while the the user downloads the merged file.
With `each_byte` the download bandwidth is really poor because of the small blocksize (1 byte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000918:

```
# iterate over fixed length records.
open("fixed-record-file") {|f|
  while record = f.read(256)
    ...
  end
}
```

And you can always wrap it within each-ish method.

Comment: Thank You. I tought this can only be used to iterate over files that have sizes congruent 0 mod 256.